# SimpleXML -- Strip CDATA Tags (or embed HTML markup in XML)

Tags: php, html, xml, cdata

I've just recently begun learning XML in the context of PHP and Javascript, and I've encountered a problem.

So the issue is I want to put HTML markup within the XML, and then be able to extract this via PHP and embed the HTML in a different file that's reading the XML with SimpleXML. I'm echoing it with something along the lines of

`echo $child->asXML();`

However, of course the CDATA tags are still there and it doesn't work. So, my question is, is there either a way to A. embed HTML markup in a different way that is ignored by the XML parser but can be used in an HTML document, or B. a way to strip the CDATA tags from the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just had to reload the string in the XML parser, but excluding CDATA.

```
echo simplexml_load_string($child->asXML(), null, LIBXML_NOCDATA)
```

Don't mind me.

Answer (score 0):

The CDATA tags should disappear if you use the `nodeValue` property instead of `asXML()`.

Something like

```
echo $child->nodeValue;
```

should do the job.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that nodeValue returns a SimpleXMLElement object, rather than a string or something useful. Or am I supposed to call another function on nodeValue in order to output it?

Comment: @Will does `echo (string)$child->nodeValue` work?

Comment: Still no luck. It's a regular node object [I think], so I doubt I could typecast it any which way.

Comment: @Will awww sorry, I mixed up nodeValue with `textContent`. Does that work any better?

Comment: That appears to return a SimpleXMLElement object as well, except for some reason whenever I output it. OOP -- found it, just had to search a little harder.